# DATEDIFF ranges by created date utilizing outer date to count age history by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Utilizing DATEDIFF to find a difference in days between two dates is easy and I have utilized it many times in the past. What I cannot seem to figure out this time is the when i need to utilize an "outer" reference I guess. The object of my query is to "go back in time" and look at tickets in my SQL Server database. Then count how old they were if they happened to still be open in that month based on its first day and then place the counts in buckets such as "0 to 30 days old", "31 to 60 days old", "61 to 90 days old" and "Above 91". I have the following test dataset here:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[taskDB]    Script Date: 12/8/2020 9:49:25 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[taskDB](
    [ticket] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [created] [date] NULL,
    [closed] [date] NULL,
    [rating] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023345', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-01-17' AS Date), N'Low', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023346', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023347', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-09-20' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023348', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-06' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023349', CAST(N'2020-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023350', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023351', CAST(N'2019-12-22' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'High', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023352', CAST(N'2019-11-07' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023353', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'Low', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023354', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023356', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023357', CAST(N'2019-08-06' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-07-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023358', CAST(N'2019-10-04' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'Low', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023359', CAST(N'2019-12-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-02-25' AS Date), N'High', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023360', CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023361', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'High', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023362', CAST(N'2019-09-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-06' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023363', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-08' AS Date), N'High', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023365', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-12-08' AS Date), N'Low', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023364', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-05' AS Date), N'High', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023366', CAST(N'2020-06-03' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'High', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023368', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'High', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023367', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'1900-01-01' AS Date), N'Low', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023371', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Low', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023370', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023434', CAST(N'2020-09-03' AS Date), NULL, N'Low', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'012312', CAST(N'2020-08-14' AS Date), NULL, N'High', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'054312', CAST(N'2020-10-16' AS Date), NULL, N'Medium', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'023423', CAST(N'2020-01-18' AS Date), NULL, N'High', N'Open')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'032444', CAST(N'2019-12-22' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-02-22' AS Date), N'High', N'Resolved')
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [status]) VALUES (N'043234', CAST(N'2020-02-24' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-06-07' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Resolved')
GO
```

The query I have constructed so far is as follows:

```
declare @FromDate datetime, 
            @ToDate datetime;
    
    SET @FromDate = ('2020-08-01 00:00:00.000');
    SET @ToDate = (Select max(created) From [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB]);
  
    declare @openTicketsBM table (firstDayOfMonth datetime, firstDayNextMonth datetime, year int, month int, Rating int, ZTT int, TTS int, STN int, ANN int)
    
    Insert into @openTicketsBM(firstDayOfMonth, firstDayNextMonth, year, month)
    
    Select top  (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
                        dateadd(month, number, @FromDate),
                  dateadd(month, number + 1, @FromDate),
                 year(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate)),
                  month(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate))
                  from [master].dbo.spt_values 
                  where [type] = N'P' order by number;
    
    update R
    Set  R.ZTT = (Select COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) > 0 AND DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) from [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB] where created < R.firstDayNextMonth and NOT status like 'Risk Accepted' and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
         R.TTS = (Select COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) >= 31 AND DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) <= 60 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) from [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB] where created < R.firstDayNextMonth and NOT status like 'Risk Accepted' and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
         R.STN = (Select COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) >= 61 AND DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) <= 90 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) from [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB] where created < R.firstDayNextMonth and NOT status like 'Risk Accepted' and (closed >= R.firstDayNextMonth or closed = '' or closed is null)),
         R.ANN = (Select COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, created, R.firstDayOfMonth) > 90 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) from [TestDB].[dbo].[taskDB] where created < R.firstDayNextMonth and NOT status like 'Risk Accepted' and (closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth or closed = '' or closed is null))
  
    From @openTicketsBM R
    
    select  CAST(year AS VARCHAR(50)) + '/' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(50)) AS date,
            ZTT,
            TTS,
            STN,
            ANN
          
            
    from @openTicketsBM
```

When running this query the following error is generated:

```
Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.
```

This seems pretty straight forward but I am clearly missing something.

EDITT 12/18/2020 10:18am est

To clarify my logic, Lets go back in time to let say February 2020. How many tickets were open on February 1st and how old were they? results should looks like

```
date       ZTT(0-30)  TTS(31-60)  STN(61-90) ANN(91+)
2020/2        5          3           3           1
```

Comment: A simple explanation of what you want to do would help.  I imagine you can reproduce the problem with a simpler example.

Comment: Well we definitely have sample data, @GordonLinoff , and by far in the best form; DDL and DML statements.

Comment: This is as simple as I could make it based on my current problem.

Comment: Yes, but we don't know the logic you are trying to do here, @mister.cake , nor the expected results. That's what we also need.

Comment: Okay i added an edit.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm leaving this answer purely based on one portion of your post:

> How many tickets were open on February 1st [2020] and how old were they?

Just based on this quote alone...your problem sounds fairly straight forward.

You have a table of tickets with `created` and `closed` dates. So your first step would be to get a list of all tickets that existed on or before Feb 1st.

That's simple:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.taskDB
WHERE created <= '2020-02-01'
```

Now, we want to eliminate any tickets that were closed at that time. Based on the data in your sample, for closed dates, I see `NULL` values and I see `1900-01-01`, I'm going to assume in both of these cases, that means the ticket is still open.

So that means that in order for a ticket to be considered open on a particular day, let's call it `@AsOfDate`, then one of these must be true...

- `closed IS NULL`
- `closed = '1900-01-01'`
- `closed >= @AsOfDate` - If a ticket was closed the same day it was open, we'll count that as open on that day. But you can change this to `>` to exclude those tickets. That's up to you.

Now let's combine this all into a single query:

```sql
DECLARE @AsOfDate date = '2020-02-01'
SELECT *, TicketAge = DATEDIFF(DAY, created, @AsOfDate)
FROM dbo.taskDB
WHERE created <= @AsOfDate -- Only look at tickets that existed at this point in time
    AND (closed IS NULL OR closed >= @AsOfDate OR closed < created) -- Only look at tickets that were open
ORDER BY created DESC
```

This query does not produce the same numbers as the numbers you were expecting in your post...but I'm also not sure if your numbers are accurate. Your numbers add up to 12 tickets, for Feb 1st 2020...but I see 9 tickets which existed and were open at that time.

---

#### EDIT 1:

You asked how you would go about implementing my solution against your table of dates...Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT ot.firstDayOfMonth
    , [0-30]    = SUM(IIF(x.TicketAge BETWEEN 0 AND 30, 1, 0))
    , [31-60]   = SUM(IIF(x.TicketAge BETWEEN 31 AND 60, 1, 0))
    , [61-90]   = SUM(IIF(x.TicketAge BETWEEN 61 AND 90, 1, 0))
    , [91+]     = SUM(IIF(x.TicketAge >= 91, 1, 0))
FROM @openTicketsBM ot
    LEFT JOIN #taskDB t ON t.created <= ot.firstDayOfMonth -- Only look at tickets that existed at this point in time
        AND (t.closed IS NULL OR t.closed >= ot.firstDayOfMonth OR t.closed < t.created) -- Only look at tickets that were open
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TicketAge = DATEDIFF(DAY, t.created, ot.firstDayOfMonth)) x
GROUP BY ot.firstDayOfMonth
```

* *Edited query so that it uses a `LEFT JOIN` instead, this way, you will see months where no tickets were open*

---

Some unrelated observations and personal reccomendations...

- Don't refer to dates as `''` which then gets converted to `'1900-01-01'`. If you're using that as a way of indicating a ticket is open, why not `NULL`?
- Use column names that are clear/self descriptive. "created" or "closed" sound (to me) like flag/bit columns, not date columns. I'd use something like `CreateDateUTC` and `CloseDateUTC`.
- Why use ticket numbers stored as strings, and not `int IDENTITY(1,1)`?
- You should normalize your table. Instead of using strings for `rating` and `status`, use foreign key columns linking to a lookup table.
- Instead of relying on `spt_values` as a tally table, create a permanent date/calendar table ([here's an example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)), or use an on the fly tally table like this:

```sql
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tally','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tally; --SELECT * FROM #tally
WITH c1 AS (SELECT x.x FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(x)) -- 10
    , c2(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM c1 x CROSS JOIN c1 y) -- 10 * 10
    , c3(rn) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) FROM c2) -- Add zero record, and row numbers
INTO #tally
SELECT x.rn
FROM c3 x
```

Comment: So in my question instead of using @AsOfDate for the date diff i am utilizing  the value (R.firstDayOfMonth) for each 1st day of month in the table generated called ```@openTicketsBM R```. SQL is throwing an error indicating this is an "Outer Reference". Is there a way i can still utilize that value?

Comment: @mister.cake see `Edit 1` in the post, I've applied my solution to your table of dates.